# Xfce: Why do changes made with menulibre or alacarte not show up in the startmenu

Tags: xfce, menu-editor

This question relates to a computer running Xubuntu 14.04 LTE. The start menu manager program is the whisker menu. (BTW: on another computer with Xubuntu 16.04 LTE I have a different start menu, there it is called Anwendungmenü but its logo looks similar to that of whiskermenu. **What are the file names of these two programs and where are they stored?**)

On this computer, both menulibre and alacarte are installed. They seem to work on the same data. A change made in menulibre shows up in alacarte, but it does not influence the whiskermenu which of course I want to do with it.

This is also true after logging out and logging in again.

I wanted to create a starter for

pwsafe %f

and I associated to it an icon which I had made as a png file from the logo on the start screen of pwsafe (Password Safe).

But the arrangement of starters in the shown whiskermenu did not reflect the changes I had made in menulibre and which also showed up in alacarte.

**What's wrong here and how do I effectively add a starter for pwsafe?**